# nodejs - does forEach create a reference cycle?

Tags: node.js, foreach, reference-cycle

I am a newbie in `NodeJS`, my background is `Swift`.

When facing `forEach`, I wonder if it would create a reference cycle?

```
const array = [1, 3, 2, 4]
arrach.forEach(function(element) {
    doSomething(element)
})

function doSomething(number) {
    // ...
}
```

In `Swift`, the code above will create a reference cycle since the closure has referenced to a function in `self`, which is `doSomething`. Is this also a case in NodeJS?

Regards,

Comment: `arrach.forEach(function(element, index, array) ...`

Comment: @Aikon, what do you mean?

Comment: Js has the same cycle as Swift. `function doSmth(e) { console.log(e); }; [1,2,3].forEach(doSmth);`.

Comment: What should I do to `solve` this cycle?